# qsub inside system2 function

Tags: r, qsub

I would like to run qsub job via R system2(). The .sh script itself requires some arguments and I'm not sure how to pass them.
I did the following but nothing seems to happen - the job is submitted to qsub but it dissapears and I don't get the results from the script's output.

arg1, arg2, arg3 are command line arguments required by script.sh

```
arg1<-"first"
arg2<-"second"
arg3<-"third"

system2("qsub", stdout="log.out", stderr="log.err", 
         args="-cwd -v arg1,arg2,arg3 -o out.txt -e err.txt script.sh")
```

I guess the variables arg1, arg2 and arg3 are not visible within this string. How can I pass them in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

The `args` argument to `system2` should be a character vector of separate arguments, not a single string separated by spaces. Thus, it should look something like:

```
system2("qsub", stdout="log.out", stderr="log.err", 
         args=c("-cwd", "-v", "arg1,arg2,arg3", "-o",
                "out.txt", "-e", "err.txt", "script.sh"))
```

When it's given a single string, it will escape the spaces, which means qsub (or any command) would not know they are separate arguments.

Alternatively, if you'd rather write the arguments as a single space-separated string, you could use `strsplit` to split it up:

```
system2("qsub", stdout="log.out", stderr="log.err", 
         args=strsplit("-cwd -v arg1,arg2,arg3 -o out.txt -e err.txt script.sh", " ")[[1]])
```

Comment: I did it as you adviced me but I still get nothing. Even out.txt and err.txt are not created.

Comment: @AirelleJab Is there anything in `log.out` or `log.err`? Also, just in case `-cwd` isn't working, please check your home directory for those files

Comment: In log.out there is a message that the job has been submitted "Your job 11 ("script.sh") has been submitted". Log.err is empty,  I've checked my /home but nothing new there.

Comment: What happens if you just do `qsub -cwd -v arg1,arg2,arg3 -o out.txt -e err.txt script.sh` directly, in that same directory?

Comment: It' working - it is added to the queue. I'm using it inside Shiny server and this script is triggered when the user presses the button, but without qsub (running only script,sh inside system2) it works even inside server.

EDIT: But in this case out and err are also not created